# Aggregate Solr facets

Tags: solr

I need to query Solr 7.4 to extract the "average hourly document count". What i would like is something like a +1HOUR range facet on a time field (so far so good), count documents in each bucket (so far so good) and then count the average value of this count.

I've come up with this really simple json facet:

```
{
    reference: {
        type: "range",
        field : "time",
        start : "NOW/HOUR-7DAYS",
        end : "NOW/HOUR",
        gap : "+1HOUR"
    }
}
```

And the result is like this:

```
...
 "facets": {
    "count": 710104,
    "reference": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "val": "2020-02-11T09:00:00Z",
          "count": 2097 <------ average on these values
        },
        {
          "val": "2020-02-11T10:00:00Z",
          "count": 2268 <------ average on these values
        },
...
```

Is it possible to let solr extract the average of values labeled as "average on these values" on the response?

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: I doubt if that's possible but you do get the number of buckets for those 7 days and you can get the total count in the 7 day period. You can then do the math, right?

Comment: A sub-facet with stat functions should do that if I'm reading your question correctly? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/json-facet-api.html#stat-facet-functions

Comment: Thank toy @WinnieDaPooh. I'm building a system in which queries and processing based on result needs to be the most configurable and generic as possible. Moving arithmetic operations out of the solr query, would require specific implementation (now a division, but tomorrow... who knows).

Comment: I don't think it is enough. The data i need to average on is omputed by bucketing. Il try to get deeper on this anyway. Thanks.

Comment: If you already have not looked into streaming expression then you should. Good luck. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/math-expressions.html